# @Html.BeginForm with a variable controller name

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a shared partial view from which I need to call a controller action but won't know which controller until runtime.

In each of my controller I assign the name to the ViewBag but the following won't compile.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", ViewBag.CurrentController))
```

How can I work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a cast to `string` on to the `ViewBag` call:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", (string)ViewBag.CurrentController))
```

The [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String%29) your trying to match expects a string as the controller name, and ViewBag isn't strongly typed.

Comment: The compiler didn't like it with .ToString but worked fine when I used (string)  cast syntax: @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", (string)ViewBag.CurrentController))